# I need to execute one method multiple time as async in c#

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I need to execute one method multiple time as async in c# with using the wait operator. following is my code

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SentSMS(null, creation.SenderMobile, messageToSender));
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SentSMS(null, creation.ReceiverMobile, messageToReciver));
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SentSMS(null, empMobile, messageToEmp));
```

```
private async Task SentSMS(SMSReceived smsrecived, string mobilenumber ,string message)
{
    try
    {
        sent = new SMSSent();
        sent.MobileNumber = Util.ParseMobileNo(mobilenumber);
        sent.MobileOperator = Util.GetMobileOperator(mobilenumber);
        sent.QueryCodeId = 1;
        sent.ReplyByTelcoID = 1;
        sent.ReplyText = message;
        sent.ReplyByTelcoID = 1;
        sent.SMSReceivedId = (smsrecived == null ? 0 : smsrecived.ID);
        sent.SMSSentDate = DateTime.Now;
        sent.Status = 1;
        sentBL.Save(sent);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

[image]
The problem is , when the last request started , it override rest of 2 records. After execution of this code, i have checked in database it save one/same record 3 times.

do not tell me i am passing same data thrice. All the values are different.
I need help. Let me know if i am lacking some where. I have also tried Task.Run(). I do not want to use await . In await , results are also same

Screenshot has attached of database

Comment: What does `sent` point to? I don't see it declared anywhere in the function so I assume it's a common variable inside the class? If so, it will in fact be replaced each time the function is invoked. You probably might want to declare it like this: `var sent = new SMSSent();` and then return it at the end.

Comment: @Szab yes , sent is global variable . it declared at top

Comment: Clearly each task needs it's own `sent`.

Comment: @Igor i do not want to wait the main method. this SentSMS method must work async because i do not want any result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> do not tell me i am passing same data thrice. All the values are different.

But they're not, because `sent` is a field, and it is being overwritten, and then all the values are the same.

Make `sent` a local created inside the method.